# How to make eclipse tomcat use ant script to create a war and then deploy it

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, ant

In eclipse, to run my dynamic web application, I do the following:

```
right-click on the project >> Run as >> Run on server
```

and then the application is deployed on the tomcat.

Now I want tomcat to use my ant script to build the war and then deploy that war.

How can I do this in eclipse?

Comment: Other than `right click ant script >> run as >> ant build`?

Comment: Point of order, Tomcat won't know what to do with an Ant script.  Eclipse executes Ant.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the Ant script -> select "Run As" -> "Ant Build"

Select target and "Run"

There should now be an entry in the "Run" menu under "External Tools" which you can also reach with the red/green button in the toolbar (to the right of the "Run" button).